# Selenium element cannot be found error log

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a number of tests I'm running through Selenium. Whenever one fails I just have a catch surrounding the test saying that an Element could not be found.

It seems quite vague instead I want to be able to say what element can't be found and write that to my error log. Is there a way to determine what element cannot be found?

Here is some example code I am using at the moment to catch my error.

```
try
{
    base.SetUp();

    webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(
      excelSession.FindElementByName("Blank workbook"))).Click();
    webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(
      excelSession.FindElementByName("Create"))).Click();
    webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(
      excelSession.FindElementByName("New"))).Click();
    webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(
      excelSession.FindElementByName("E  Sample Data"))).Click();

    CommonMethods.IsElementDisplayed(excelSession,
      new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), 
      new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), "CreateErrorIcon",
        "Error appeard while selecting the E Sample Data button");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    CommonMethods.ExceptionHandler("Couldn't find element", 
      new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), 
      new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), excelSession);
}
```

Comment: One option is to write the exception message to the logs. The exception message will indicate the locator used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a function that will search for elements:

```
Func<RemoteWebDriver, By, IWebElement> find = (driver, by) =>
{
    var elements = driver.FindElements(by);
    if (elements.Count < 1)
    {
        var msg = $"Couldn't find element {by}";
        logger.Warn(msg);
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }

    return elements.First();
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
webDriverWait.Until(
  ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(
  find(excelSession, By.Name("Blank workbook")))
).Click();
```

Comment: Please give me a feedback. Does my code not working? Did I misunderstood a question? What wrong with this answer?

Comment: The idea is not bad but the implementation has issues. `FindElementsByName()` is not defined. OP used singular. You have logic issues in your `if-else`... you don't need the `else if` at all, just return the first element if `.Count == 0`. It would be much better to pass in a `By` locator instead of a `string`. I know OP used a `string` but that is not a good practice. `By` is much more flexible.

Comment: @JeffC Thank you for feedback, I've updated my answer. I'm using Selenium "3.4.0.0" and `FindElementsByName` is defined in `OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver` class

Comment: This is a good answer however in my case I'm searching for a windows element and I'm using `FindElementByName` rather than the `By.Name` property is there a way of using your method to fit my methodology?

Comment: @CraigGallagher Please see a [first](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45421955/1) version of my answer. Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: This worked fine for an element that didn't exist however it did add on a considerable amount of time to the test however if the element was there I would get a SocketException `Additional information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Comment: @AleksAndreev I don't get the exception anymore however it does take much longer to do the test

Comment: @CraigGallagher I don't know why this happens. `FindElements` work fine in my cases. Maybe you should create another question, like "Why FindElements slows down my test"?